# action on div - how to stop it for 1 select?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, blockui

I have a jQuery BlockUI call set up on a div that contains 'action' buttons.  Onclick, this grey's out the page to prevent doubleclicking, etc.
We've introduced a new option, and it has a select box/go button combo.

Problem is, the select box change causes it to go to the wait screen before you can hit the submit button.

How can i target the blockui to NOT fire on selects?  Unfortunately, the select name="" area is dynamic, and will constantly change as it is built from a cms, so i can't use the select[name=] targetting.  I can give it a class if necessary.
The 'else' is currently all i have.  I need to build the if top part to do nothing basically if its a select click.

```
$('.actionbuttons').click(function() {
    if($SELECT?)
       alert('select');
    }
else{
       $.blockUI({ message: '<h1>thinking...</h1>' });
    }
});
```

html:

```
<div class="actionbuttons">
  <input type="submit" name="a" value="Save" onclick="return verify(this.form);">
  <input type="submit" name="b" value="Close" onclick="return verify(this.form);">
  <select name="c" size="1" onchange="changeit();">
      <option selected="selected">Default</option>
      <!-- dont do anything when clicking here -->
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="d" value="Change C" onclick="return verify(this.form);">
</div>
```

And no, just for the record, an onchange + submit in 1 move is not acceptible due to spec.  So the button needs to be there on d to submit c.  Remember, these name alphas are dynamic and change on every page load so are useless for targetting.

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to ONLY trigger the BlockUI overlay when the `input` elements with `type="submit"` are clicked, you can simply be more specific on your selector.

**HTML**

```
<div class="actionbuttons">
    <input type="submit" name="a" value="Save" />
    <input type="submit" name="b" value="Close" />
    <select name="c" size="1">
        <option selected="selected">Default</option>
        <option>Other</option>
        <!-- dont do anything when clicking here -->
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="d" value="Change C" />
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.actionbuttons input[type="submit"]').click(function (e) {
    $.blockUI({
        message: '<h1>thinking...</h1>'
    });
    verify( /* Pass in your form */ );
});

$('.actionbuttons select').change(function (e) {
    changeit();
});
```

This will trigger the behavior for any `input` elements with `type="submit"` that are children (not necessarily direct) of the container with the `actionbuttons` class. Then you do not need any logic inside of the callback function surrounding bringing up the overlay. In addition, you also have the option to move the call to `verify` directly in there as well.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VhHyE/2/)

Comment: There are links, other buttons, and such in there that all should trigger the overlay, except the select.

I figured out a workaround with the not command and a class.

$('.actionbuttons').children().not(".viewmenu").click(function() {
 $.blockUI({ message: '<h1>thinking...</h1>' }); });